# Could not find a declaration file for module 'react'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I learn Microsoft's [manual](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter#typescript-react-starter) about TypeScript + React + Redux.

I launched the command:

`npm install -S redux react-redux @types/react-redux`

But when I run the command `npm run start` I get the error:

> Type error: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react'.
>   'C:/lab/my-app/node_modules/react/index.js' implicitly has an 'any'
>   type.

Ok, I run the command: `npm i @types/react`. now I get other error:

> Type error: Module '"../../node_modules/@types/react-redux"' has no
>   exported member 'Dispatch'.  TS2305

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show your code that's associated with your index file?

Comment: I found the solution here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter/issues/160#issuecomment-402800483

Comment: I had this issue `Could not find a declaration file for module 'react'` and solved it be reinstalling `node` and `react` @types then restarting my development server `npm run start`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I initially created a React with TypeScript project, it made no sense since I had not started any work yet.

So in terminal I ran:

`rm -rf node_modules/ && npm install`

Then:

`npm run start`

And I was able to see the main landing page.

Comment: In addition, I had to also delete my package-lock.json to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

run the following:
`pm install @types/react`
It works for me!